# Prolog program to exclude integer from result list

Tags: list, prolog

I need to split a list into one that is bigger than N and one smaller, while ignoring any non-integers. It works perfectly except that it throws an exception when i include non integers. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please:

```
split([],N, [],[]).
split([HeadOrig | TailOrig], N, L1, TailOrig):- 
    \+ integer(HeadOrig), 
    split(TailOrig, N, L1, TailOrig).
split([HeadOrig|TailOrig],N, [HeadOrig|Tail1],L2):-
    integer(HeadOrig), HeadOrig >= N, 
    !,
    split(TailOrig, N, Tail1, L2).
split([HeadOrig | TailOrig], N, L1, [HeadOrig | Tail2]) :- 
    integer(HeadOrig), HeadOrig < N, 
    !,
    split(TailOrig, N, L1, Tail2).
```

Comment: OK i saw that now (have edited original code above) but it now just returns 'false' if i give it a list with a letter e.g.: [1,2,'a'] . No more error, but now does not continue with the splitting

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the last term in that clause should not be `TailOrig`:

```
split([], _, [],[]).

split([HeadOrig | TailOrig], N, L1, L2):-
    \+ integer(HeadOrig),
    split(TailOrig, N, L1, L2),
    !.

split([HeadOrig|TailOrig], N, [HeadOrig|Tail1], L2):-
    integer(HeadOrig), HeadOrig >= N,
    !,
    split(TailOrig, N, Tail1, L2).

split([HeadOrig | TailOrig], N, L1, [HeadOrig | Tail2]) :-
    integer(HeadOrig), HeadOrig < N,
    !,
    split(TailOrig, N, L1, Tail2).
```